# How to put multiple json records into mongoDB?

Tags: python, json, mongodb

I have Json large json data in a large file in the following format:

```
{"created_at":"Wed Apr 15 16:59:38 +0000 2020","id":1250468838409490432,"id_str":"1250468838409490432"}

{"created_at":"Thu Apr 16 16:59:38 +0000 2020","id":1250468838404390433,"id_str":"1250468838409490433"}
.....................
.....................




 millions of rows




.....................
```

I have already tried a lot of different things like:

```
mongoimport --jsonArray --db YourDatabase --collection YourCollection --file Yourfile.json
```

That doesn't help and gives the error :

```
 E  QUERY    [js] uncaught exception: SyntaxError: unexpected token: identifier :
```

I also tried writing a custom python program and that didn't do it either :

```
import json
from pymongo import MongoClient

client = MongoClient('localhost', 27017)
db = client['twitter']
collection = db['myCollection']

with open('C:\\myDatata.json') as f:
    for line in f:
        document = (DBObject) JSON.parse(line)
        collection.insert(document)

client.close()
```

This gives me different errors.

I understand from reading other answers like

[Unexpected end of JSON input in MongoDB Compass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56151099/unexpected-end-of-json-input-in-mongodb-compass)

[Insert json file into mongodb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19441228/insert-json-file-into-mongodb)

that the new line shouldn't be there and all but the data is too big to process. 
I tried same thing using Compass as well but failed. 
When I copy a single record I am able to insert it through compass `insert data` option but unable to insert two or more rows. If I choose import data and pass my JSON file then Compass gives an error saying error in the given data.

I have no clue what to do. I am looking for some python program probably a modification on what I have through which I can insert data into the DB.
Or any other way of inserting such large document into the db either with Compass, mongo command prompt, or python.

Comment: have you tried using sed to remove the blank line before importing?

Comment: what is the size of the file?

Answer (score 0):

if the file is really big as you say Mongo have size limit check:

[https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/document/][1]

you could try to compress the JSON file with:

```
ZIPJSON_KEY = 'base64(zip(o))'

def json_zip(j):

    j = {
        ZIPJSON_KEY: base64.b64encode(
            zlib.compress(
                json.dumps(j).encode('utf-8')
            )
        ).decode('ascii')
    }

    return j

def mongoinsertone(path):
        file_data = json_zip(path)
        # conncect to the specific collection on MongoDB
        collection = db["collection name here"]
        # delete previous version and replace it with new one
        collection.delete_many({})
        collection.insert_one(file_data)
        return file_data

mongoinsertone("file path here")
```

then when you pull back the file make sure you decompress it.

```
ZIPJSON_KEY = 'base64(zip(o))'
def json_unzip(j, insist=True):
    try:
        assert (j[ZIPJSON_KEY])
        assert (set(j.keys()) == {ZIPJSON_KEY})
    except:
        if insist:
            raise RuntimeError("JSON not in the expected format {" + str(ZIPJSON_KEY) + ": zipstring}")
        else:
            return j

    try:
        j = zlib.decompress(base64.b64decode(j[ZIPJSON_KEY]))
    except:
        raise RuntimeError("Could not decode/unzip the contents")

    try:
        j = json.loads(j)
    except:
        raise RuntimeError("Could interpret the unzipped contents")

    return j
```