# Cannot import JSON containing an array using MongDB Compass

Tags: json, mongodb, mongodb-compass

I'm trying to import documents containing arrays from JSON file - like this one:

```
   {"aaa":["sss","aaa"]}
```

Than MongoDB Compass raises

"Error importing

Callback called multiple times"

Am I doing something stupid or it is a bug?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56151099/